# Separating a column using big spaces in strings in R

Tags: r, dataframe

This is my data frame, composed only of the 1 observation. This is a long string where 4 different parts are identifiable:

```
example <- "4.6             (19 ratings)                                                         Course Ratings are calculated from individual students’ ratings and a variety of other signals, like age of rating and reliability, to ensure that they reflect course quality fairly and accurately.                                                                                                            151 students enrolled                                                                    "
df <- data.frame(example)
```

As you can see, the first observation is composed of a string with 4 different parts: rating (4.6), number of ratings (19 ratings), a sentence (Course...accurately), and students enrolled (151).

I employed the `separate()` function to divide that column in 4 one:

```
df1 <- separate(df, example, c("Rating", "Number of rating", "Sentence", "Students"), sep = "     ")
```

Thus, this does not behave as expected.

Any idea.

**UPDATE**:

This is what I get with your comment @nicola

```
> df1 <- separate(df, example, c("Rating", "Number of rating", "Sentence", "Students"), sep=" {4,}")
Warning message:
Expected 4 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 1 rows [1].
```

Comment: Try with something like `sep=" {4,}"` inside `separate`.

Comment: @nicola I tried what you said, with no success

Comment: It works on your example though. You should provide a better example, showing why it doesn't work.

Comment: I am getting some warnings (see update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
x <- str_split(example, "  ") %>%
    unlist()
x <- x[x != ""]
df <- tibble("a", "b", "c", "d")
df[1, ] <- x
colnames(df) <- c("Rating", "Number of rating", "Sentence", "Students")

> str(df)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Rating          : chr "4.6"
 $ Number of rating: chr " (19 ratings)"
 $ Sentence        : chr " Course Ratings are calculated from individual students’ ratings and a variety of other signals, like age of ra"| __truncated__
 $ Students        : chr "151 students enrolled"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two keys to the answer. The first is to the correct regex used as separator `sep = "[[:space:]]{2,}"` which means two or more whitespace (`\\s{2,}` would be a more common alterantive). The second one is that your example actually has a lot a trailing whitespace which `separate()` tries to put into another column. It can simply be removed using `trimws()`. The solution therefore looks like this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

example <- "4.6             (19 ratings)                                                         Course Ratings are calculated from individual students’ ratings and a variety of other signals, like age of rating and reliability, to ensure that they reflect course quality fairly and accurately.                                                                                                            151 students enrolled                                                                    "
df <- data.frame(example)

df_new <- df %>%
  mutate(example = trimws(example)) %>% 
  separate(col = "example", 
           into = c("rating", "number_of_ratings", "sentence", "students_enrolled"), 
           sep = "[[:space:]]{2,}")




as_tibble(df_new)
    # A tibble: 1 x 4
      rating number_of_ratings sentence                                                                    students_enrolled
      <chr>  <chr>             <chr>                                                                       <chr>            
    1 4.6    (19 ratings)      Course Ratings are calculated from individual students’ ratings and a vari~ 151 students enr~
```

tibble is only used to formatting the output.

Comment: `trimws` is a function from base R.

Comment: Yes, I realised this the moment I posted. I was thinking of `stri_trim_both()` which isn't really necessary here...

Answer (score 0):

Certainly possible with the `stringr` package and a bit of regular expressions:

```
  rating_mean n_ratings n_students                         descr
1        4.65        19        151    "Course (...) accurately."
```

#### Code

```
library(stringr)

# create result data frame
result <- data.frame(cbind(rating_mean = 0, n_ratings = 0, n_students = 0, descr = 0))

# loop through rows of example data frame
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    # replace spaces
    example[i, 1] <- gsub("\\s+", " ", example[i, 1])
    # match and extract mean rating
    result[i, 1] <- as.numeric(str_match(example[i], "^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+"))
    # match and extract number of ratings
    result[i, 2] <- as.numeric(str_match(str_match(example[i, 1], "\\(.+\\)"), "[0-9]+"))
    # match and extract number of enrolled students
    result[i, 3] <- as.numeric(str_match(str_match(example[i, 1], "\\s[0-9].+$"), "[0-9]+"))
    # match and extract sentence
    result[i, 4] <- str_match(example[i, 1], "[A-Z].+\\.")
}
```

#### Data

```
example <- "4.65             (19 ratings)                                                         Course Ratings are calculated from individual students’ ratings and a variety of other signals, like age of rating and reliability, to ensure that they reflect course quality fairly and accurately.                                                                                                            151 students enrolled                                                                    "
example <- data.frame(example, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Info: I edited the data a bit (`rating` of 4.65 instead of 4.6) to show a slightly more robust approach.